# How to run an exe file on raspberry startup

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, autostart

I'm on the Raspbian version 4.19 (The last one) and I want to run a .exe at my Raspberry pi 3B+ startup. I found that I sould add to the autostart file the path of my .exe but I can't find it on my Raspbian version.

I found this path for the autostart file : ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

But in "/.config" I just have lxpanel and lxterminal...

Is someone here who already have the same issue ?

Comment: You could maybe run it from `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: Questions about the Raspberry Pi and its utilities should, instead, be asked on https://https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll try there !

Comment: But Stackoverflow is a general forum, no ? And I think my answer could help other people in the same situation. I don't really want to delete it, I found it legitimate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last Raspbian version, the autostart has been moved. It's now there:

```
/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

There you can add this line to execute your exe:

```
@sudo mono MyPath.exe
```

"mono" is here for windows executable, but you need to install it before "sudo apt-get install mono-complete"

Answer (score 0):

To start after desktop (GUI) loads, use this path:

sudo nano /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart